# How to use asyncio to get responses from elasticsearch in Python?

Tags: elasticsearch, python-asyncio

I am trying to use asyncio to get responses from elasticsearch. I am gatering queries to elastic in a list, then I am iterating through that list to make response for each of that query.

that is my code:

`

```
async def make_response(query, es):

    res = await es.search(index='index_name', query=query, size=10000)
    
    return res

query_list = make_queries_list_db()
```

```
async def main():

    list_of_res = []
    for enum, el in enumerate(query_list):
        es = AsyncElasticsearch(port, auth)
        list_of_res.append(make_response(query_list[enum],es))
    await asyncio.gather(*list_of_res)

asyncio.run(main())
```

`

Doing that I am still having errors, like "Unclosed client session" or "connection time exceed".
How to use asyncio with elasticsearch in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

So I had exactly the same issue and managed to cobble together the answer from the pypi project https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch-async/

My original code looked like this

```
import asyncio
from elasticsearch import AsyncElasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import async_scan

es = AsyncElasticsearch(
    host="localhost",
    port=9200,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=False,
    ssl_show_warn=False,
    http_auth=("user", "password"),
)


async def main():
    async for doc in async_scan(
        client=es, query={"query": {"match": {"_id": "baa"}}}, index="foo"
    ):
        print(doc)


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

To fix the problem, I simply added the following to the end of the code

```
loop.run_until_complete(es.transport.close())
loop.close()
```

It's not exactly your code, but hopefully helps point you in the direction you need.